# Iterating through 2 arrays to render matching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

In my React project I have 2 API calls that gives me 2 arrays for example

```
const allGenres = [{id: 1, name: "Action"}, {id: 2, name: "Adventure"}, {id: 3, name: "Animation"}];
const specificFilm = [1, 3];
```

I want to iterate through these 2 arrays to compare them and display genre name if Ids are the same, so for above example it would display Action and Animation.

This is what I've done but I think my approach is not good for performance.

```
{allGenres.map((genre) =>
   specificFilm.map((id) =>
      genre.id === id ? <Chip label={genre.name} /> : ""
   )
)}
```

[link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-hooks-yii1u0?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set and reverse your loop to filter first like so :

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const allGenres = [
    { id: 1, name: "Action" },
    { id: 2, name: "Adventure" },
    { id: 3, name: "Animation" }
  ];
  const specificFilm = new Set([1, 3]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {allGenres.filter(({ id }) => specificFilm.has(id)).map(genre => <span>
        {genre.name}
      </span>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```